# Request matched endpoint 405 HTTP Method Not Supported

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, adfs, endpoint

This sound simple I just change from post to get but the do not help. I am trying to make a login against ADF2016 and when I am getting redirected back, I get this error in my backend. Now I have tried all changes I can think of so it time ask a question here with hope of a resolution.

The trace log leading up the exception:

```
x=Microsoft.AspNetCore
x.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: AuthenticationScheme: Identity.External signed in.
x.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST https://.../backend/adfscallback application/x-www-form-urlencoded 5316 - 302 - - 318.8660ms
x.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://.../backend/adfscallback - -
x.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware: All hosts are allowed.
x.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector: Performing protect operation to key {53f014ae-56d8-44e9-b9c8-d5f9b04ec57d} with purposes ('C:\home\site\wwwroot\frontend\backend', 'SessionMiddleware').
x.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher: 1 candidate(s) found for the request path '/adfscallback'
x.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware: Request matched endpoint '405 HTTP Method Not Supported'
x.Authentication.WsFederation.WsFederationHandler: Error from RemoteAuthentication: No message..
x.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
 ---> System.Exception: No message.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

The trace leading up to the error after changing HttpPost to HttpGet

```
2021-12-06 15:49:32.755 +00:00 [Trace] Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector: Performing unprotect operation to key {53f014ae-56d8-44e9-b9c8-d5f9b04ec57d} with purposes ('C:\home\site\wwwroot\frontend\backend', 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation.WsFederationHandler', 'WsFederation', 'v1').
2021-12-06 15:49:32.976 +00:00 [Trace] Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector: Performing unprotect operation to key {53f014ae-56d8-44e9-b9c8-d5f9b04ec57d} with purposes ('C:\home\site\wwwroot\frontend\backend', 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware', 'Identity.External', 'v2').
2021-12-06 15:49:32.977 +00:00 [Trace] Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector: Performing protect operation to key {53f014ae-56d8-44e9-b9c8-d5f9b04ec57d} with purposes ('C:\home\site\wwwroot\frontend\backend', 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware', 'Identity.External', 'v2').
2021-12-06 15:49:32.977 +00:00 [Trace] Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy.CookiePolicyMiddleware: Needs consent: False.
2021-12-06 15:49:32.978 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: AuthenticationScheme: Identity.External signed in.
2021-12-06 15:49:32.978 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST https://testlakemedelshantering.skane.se/backend/adfscallback application/x-www-form-urlencoded 5312 - 302 - - 286.3371ms
2021-12-06 15:49:33.015 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://testlakemedelshantering.skane.se/backend/adfscallback - -
2021-12-06 15:49:33.015 +00:00 [Trace] Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware: All hosts are allowed.
2021-12-06 15:49:33.015 +00:00 [Trace] Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector: Performing protect operation to key {53f014ae-56d8-44e9-b9c8-d5f9b04ec57d} with purposes ('C:\home\site\wwwroot\frontend\backend', 'SessionMiddleware').
2021-12-06 15:49:33.015 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher: 1 candidate(s) found for the request path '/adfscallback'
2021-12-06 15:49:33.015 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher: Endpoint 'LakemedelsappenWeb.Controllers.AdfsCallbackController.CallbackAsync (LakemedelsappenWeb)' with route pattern 'AdfsCallback' is valid for the request path '/adfscallback'
2021-12-06 15:49:33.015 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware: Request matched endpoint 'LakemedelsappenWeb.Controllers.AdfsCallbackController.CallbackAsync (LakemedelsappenWeb)'
2021-12-06 15:49:33.015 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation.WsFederationHandler: Error from RemoteAuthentication: No message..
2021-12-06 15:49:33.188 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
 ---> System.Exception: No message.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
2021-12-06 15:49:33.301 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET https://testlakemedelshantering.skane.se/backend/adfscallback - - - 500 - text/html;+charset=utf-8 286.2665ms
```

The declaration for function I try to call:

```
[HttpPost]        
public async Task<ContentResult> CallbackAsync(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
```

My startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     String connectionString = GetSqlServerConnectionString();
     services.AddSession();

     services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
           options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

     services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
          .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();


     services.AddAuthentication()
          .AddWsFederation(options =>
     {
          options.MetadataAddress = "https://.../FederationMetadata.xml";

          options.Wtrealm = "....";
                
           options.Wreply = "https://.../backend/adfscallback";

          options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/adfscallback");

     });

     services.AddControllersWithViews();            
     }


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseSession();
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
          
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `HttpGet` in place of `HttpPost`

Comment: You have set callback path to `/adfscallback` but haven't defined the route on `CallbackAsync` method.

Comment: The route works fine if I remove the callback path from ADFS but then then the middleware want handle the authentication. I tried to remove HttpPost (not HttpGet either) altogether from the route. This resulted in that "x.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware: Request matched endpoint '405 HTTP Method Not Supported'" disappeared but I am still left with the rest of the errors including the exception. @Hamlet

Comment: So what's the error message when you change to HttpGet?

Comment: @Rena Thanks for the response. The exception is the same  and it seems to starts with "Error from RemoteAuthentication: No message..". I have no idea what is wrong or what no message means.  I added a new error-trace to the question under the heading "The trace leading up to the error after changing HttpPost to HttpGet".  Any ideas is appreciated.